# No sound from Realtek ALC887?

Tags: alsa, realtek

I built a neat little system with and Intel Core i5 and a MSI H110M motherboard. The motherboard has a Realtek ALC887-VD for an onboard sound card. However, it does not work. I can get sound from my microphone on both front and rear ports, but I can get no sound output from neither rear nor front. I googled around, and it seems that this is a common problem. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1, with Linux 3.13.0-85-generic.

Things I tried:

- Install proprietary drivers from Realtek (installed, but did not go through)
- Add `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, as described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/fix-hda-intel-realtek-alc887-no-sound.html)
- Reinstall ALSA and PulseAudio
- Reboot many many times
- Updating the kernel to 3.14.1-031401-generic

Comment: [Help To Debug Intel HDA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Help_To_Debug_Intel_HDA)

Comment: @CL. I would help, but unfortunately, I do not have spare time to learn C++ or whatever language they're using (seeing as it's probably not Java, which is the only language I know), just to help with the driver. I'll bookmark it tho.

Comment: Just run the alsa-info script.

Comment: @CL. That gives me quite a bunch of "[[: not found" messages. The output file is saved but it's quite long, where do I post it?

Comment: I followed the steps [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) and I have sound working. Don't be daunted by the long list of to-remove packages that the command there generates, it will work after rebooting.

Comment: I don't understand what does the link have to do with this. Maybe it changed? I have installed the he and it still does not work

Answer (score 1):

I use Manjaro, but maybe you can use this:

```
# /etc/asound.conf

    # Use PulseAudio by default
    pcm.!default {
      type pulse
      fallback "sysdefault"
      hint {
        show on
        description "Default ALSA Output (currently PulseAudio Sound Server)"
      }
    }

    ctl.!default {
      type pulse
      fallback "sysdefault"
    }

    # vim:set ft=alsaconf:

# /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

    options snd-hda-intel model=auto index=0
```

[PulseAudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB71A.png)

[PulseAudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf3F9.png)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_AT3IONT-I

http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/audio_intel_hda#listes_d_ordinateurs_et_la_solution